# How can I position a node between two node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I would like to place a circle between two node, something like:

```
\node [sum, pos=($(sys1.east)!0.5!(sys2.west)$)](sum1) {};
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `\node[sum] (sum) at ($(sys1)!0.5!(sys2)$)) {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (sys1) {sys1};
    \node[right=3cm of sys1] (sys2) {sys2};
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt] (sum) at ($(sys1)!0.5!(sys2)$) {};
    %or
    %\path (sys1) -- node[midway,draw,circle,inner sep=2pt] {} (sys2);
    %or
    %\draw ($(sys1)!0.5!(sys2)$) circle (2pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]